# WCF service inside a Web application is not working through RESTCLIENT?

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, restful-url, rest-client

I have added a RESTful WCF service inside a Web application(Righclicked solution and added WCF service) and while running it is exposing the url as `svcutil.exe http://localhost:62783/Service1.svc?wsdl` but i have tried calling that service UriTemplate from a RESTCLIENT like `http://localhost:62783/AuthenticateUser` it is throwing an error like

`HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.`

But if i create a seperate RESTful WCF service and calling from a RESTCLIENT is working fine.Here is my code

```
 [OperationContract]
        string AuthenticateUser1();
```

and

```
 [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "/AuthenticateUser", Method = "GET", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        public string AuthenticateUser1()
        {

            return string.Format("Token {0}", new Guid().ToString());
        }
```

and config

```
 <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Any suggestion??

Comment: Is the `AuthenticateUser1` method you have provided, part of Service1.svc?

Comment: Yes it is a part of Service1.SVC

Comment: What is your service host's bindingAddress?

Answer (score 2):

Based on your posted config, you have a default endpoint for SOAP of `basicHttpBinding`, which is (by default) mapped to the `http` scheme.  I've done very little with REST, but I believe you will need to add an endpoint using `webHttpBinding` to do REST, and most likely the URL will need to be `http://localhost:62783/Service1.svc/AuthenticateUser` (note the inclusion of the service file), though I'm not 100% sure on that one.

To add a REST endpoint, do something like this in your service's config file:

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior name="">
        <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
        <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
      </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
    <!-- Added for REST -->
    <endpointBehaviors>
      <behavior name="REST">
        <webHttp />
      </behavior>
    </endpointBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
  <!-- REST endpoint -->
  <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding"
            contract="<contract name with namespace>"
            behaviorConfiguration="REST"> 
  <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
</system.serviceModel>
```

Again, REST is not my strong point, but this should hopefully get you pointed in the right direction at least.

Comment: Thanks..i have tried as in this link and now its working http://www.kongsli.net/nblog/2011/04/06/adding-wcf-rest-services-to-existing-asp-net-web-application/